# Defining a known time series in R

Tags: time-series

Is it possible to define time series like $X_t = 0.2X_{t-1}-0.48X_{t-2}+Z_t $, $Z_t \sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$ in R and then analyze it - for example plot its ACF and PACF?

I can only find information on how to turn data into a time series and analyze that.

Answer (score 1):

This is AR(2) model, to simulate this model you may use the following [function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/arima.sim.html).

For ACF and PACF use function [acf](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/acf.html).

Comment: You are welcome!